# Module augmentation in typescript for library plugin?

Tags: typescript, bookshelf.js

I am using Bookshelf.js with Typescript. Bookshelf allows you to add plugins like this:

```
const bs = bookshelf(knex(config));
bs.plugin('registry')
```

The registry plugin adds function to this `bs` object called `model()`, but the [typings for Bookshelf](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bookshelf/index.d.ts) (look at the first interface) do not include that function. How can I use model augmentation to tell Typescript that this function exists? I have tried this:

```
// bookshelf-registry.d.ts
import Bookshelf = require("bookshelf");

declare module "bookshelf" {
    export interface Bookshelf extends Bookshelf.Events<any> {
        model(name: string, model: Function);
    }
}
```

and then when I create the bookshelf object I add `/// <reference path="./typings/bookshelf-registry.d.ts" />` at the top of the file.

However, I still get this error: `Property 'model' does not exist on type 'Bookshelf'.`

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems like it should work. One guess is name conflict. Can you try `import BS = ...` so it may not conflict with the `Bookshelf` you are trying to augment?

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting. Yeah I tried that, and it still didn't seem to be picked up. I wonder if the compiler was even considering my file, but I'm not sure how to check.

Comment: Check the bookshelf typings. If it consists of re-export , module augmentation doesn't work. There is an issue tracking this

Comment: @unional What is a "re-export"?

Comment: `export * from './a'`

Answer (score 0):

Because the `Bookshelf` interface is the module's [default export](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/bookshelf/index.d.ts#L435), augmentation is [not possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14080) at this time. An alternative solution is to write a new interface that extends `Bookshelf` and import it when you need it.

```
// bookshelf-registry.d.ts
import Bookshelf from "bookshelf";

declare module "bookshelf" {
  interface BS extends Bookshelf {
    model(name: string, model: Function);
  }
}
```

```
import bookshelf, { BS } from "bookshelf";

const bs: BS = bookshelf(...);
```